Book with a major plot point revolving around a diorama and amnesia
I read a book in the late 90s but I don't know when it was written. I feel like the genre is a thriller but I can't be sure. The only part I can remember clearly is that the main character has always avoided going into the attic but he can't remember why and one day he finally does and he finds a diorama there. I can't remember what it was a model of but it was a working model and had moving parts.
He triggers the movement and it sets off a chain reaction that ends with something nearly hitting him. He remembers that this happened before. That thing hitting him had caused amnesia and he had blocked out a whole period of time. I think the trauma happened when he was young but in the book he's grown up.
